# A helix problem

Tags: geometry

This equation
$$
x^2 + y^2 – \left(\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}\right)^2 = 0 
$$
describes a helix. 
What is the capacity of the first twist?

Comment: You should first define what you mean by "twist capacity". Also, the equation describes a closed curve in 2D, not a helix.

Comment: Basically what i mean is:  http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/E2/EB/7eaf3806d1b1e2eb.JPG 

Our math teacher gave us that problem 2 weeks ago.

Comment: This is still not very well defined. Please try and explain what you mean.

Comment: Well, to be honest, that's all our teacher explained to us and he said that's supposed to be enough for us to solve it. I could not. An equation that should characterize that curve (helix). What he wants us to find is the volume of the first twist (that i marked in the picture). To give us a clue, he said that we should solve it as a polar coordinate system. Somewhere along the salvation an integral should take place.

Comment: @Стела Димитрова:do you mean area of first twist ? equation is in 2D

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's the word. :)

Comment: As I have mentioned in my answer, the equation you have given defines a *spiral*, not a helix.

Comment: I still have trouble seeing the twists. In polar coordinates we have $\phi=\arctan y/x$, so it looks like
$$r^2=\phi^2.$$ This leaves us the two Archimedean spirals.
$r=\pm\phi$. The above is assuming the principal branch for the arcustangent. Anyway the curve will then be bounded insided the circle with radius $r=\pi/2$. If we allow other branches, then we also get $r=\pm\phi+\pi$, but plotting both of those gives a picture unlike the one in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polar co-ordinates simplify the analysis greatly. When $r^2=x^{2}+y^{2}$ and $\tan(\theta)=\frac{y}{x}$, your equation becomes simply $r=\theta$, which is the well known equation of an [Archimedean Spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral).

What I think you are trying to ask is *"What is the area enclosed by this curve as $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $2\pi$ (one revolution)"*. I will present the solution by integration, which I also presume you have seen.

The area enclosed by the polar curve $(r,\theta)$ as $\theta$ varies from $a$ to $b$ is given by the integral $$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b}r^{2}d\theta$$
In your case, $r=\theta$, so we get
$$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\theta^{2}d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{3}\theta^{3}\right]^{2\pi}_{0}=\frac{1}{6}(2\pi)^{3}=\frac{4}{3}\pi^{3}$$

If you are unfamiliar with integral calculus (which I somehow doubt) there is an article [here](http://www.macalester.edu/~bressoud/pub/CBN2.pdf) which gives a derivation from Archimedes' principles.